# Efficient way to run multiple ANOVAs on subsets of data

Tags: r, anova

I have a data set that is repeated-measures ratings of four devices (two two-level variables) for 6 dimensions (ease, confidence, comfort, control, size and fit), with a two-level between-subjects variable. Like so:

```
ptcip / grp / fdback / dur / assem / accep / freq / t.vs.r / attrib / meas / d.rating
1    RA   binary    short       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating       ease    9         2
1    RA   binary    short       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating confidence    7         1
1    RA   binary    short       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating    comfort    6         4
1    RA   binary    short       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating    control    5         3
1    RA   binary    short       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating       size    7        -1
1    RA   binary    short       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating        fit    6         0
1    RA   binary      med       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating       ease    9         6
1    RA   binary      med       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating confidence    5         6
1    RA   binary      med       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating    comfort    6         5
1    RA   binary      med       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating    control    9        -1
1    RA   binary      med       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating       size    2        -1
1    RA   binary      med       <NA>  <NA> <NA> rating        fit    8        -2
```

I need to run separate ANOVAs on each of the dimensions (we know from other analyses that the dimensions are rated differently, so including it as a factor wouldn't be very informative). What's the most efficient way to write this--split each of the dimensions off into separate data frames, or specify aov to be run on data iff attrib == "ease"? Seems like the latter would be better, but I'm new to R.

The model I am currently specifying is

```
aov(d.ratings ~ grp*fdback*dur + Error(particip/(fdback*dur))+grp, PDdonly)
```

but as that collapses over the six dimensions, it's not actually meaningful atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed subset the data frame doing something like

```
aov(d.ratings ~ grp*fdback*dur + Error(particip/(fdback*dur))+grp,
    PDdonly[attrib == "ease",])
```

Typically however, different ratings would simply be regarded as separate variables, with the data frame formated accordingly. You could then specify your model with something like

```
aov(ease ~ blablabla)
```

Comment: Oh, MAN.  R-style data structure is totally new to me (I'm used to SPSS) and I didn't even think of that.  Thanks!